# Need to make parameter as Read-Only,

Tags: report, abap, sap-selection-screens

In selection-screen, I have one parameter called 'Author' I have called the report using 'Submit' from other report and passed the value to 'Author'. Now I need to make the 'Author' parameter as Read-only. How can I do that?

I used the following code,

```
 LOOP AT SCREEN.
   IF SCREEN-NAME = 'author'.
     SCREEN-INPUT = '0'.
     MODIFY SCREEN.
     EXIT.
   ENDIF.
 ENDLOOP.
```

But it is not working. Can any one help me in resolving this?

Comment: in which event are you executing this code? It should work in 'at selection-screen output'.

Comment: i have executed in start-of-selection.

Comment: @GarlandGreene : ya, after i moved to 'at selection-screen output', it is working fine. Thanks GarlandGreene

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your code in the `at selection-screen output`-event.

Comment: Thanks GarlandGreene.. I also committed mistake in 'if'. After give 'AUTHOR' in uppercase inside conmdition it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This answer does not answer exactly your question, but perhaps it is an easier solution for your need.

If you need only a parameter for `SUBMIT` you may use

```
PARAMETERS AUTHOR NO-DISPLAY.
```

The parameter will not be visible on selection screen, but it can be used via `SUBMIT`.

This is not a 'read-only' it is a 'don't show' parameter.

Comment: I need to **Show** the value on my screen. But it should not be editable. That is **Read-Only**.